# Cleartext HTTP traffic error while using http.get() method in Nativescript angular app

Tags: php, angular, nativescript

Iam trying to use http service to get the data from the server(I have a godaddy server where their is my file named as get_user.php).In my app iam implement a server request using NativeScriptHttpClientModule.Inside the get_user.php i have returned the data in JSON format.I just want a simple http request to be exicuted succesfully but their is error.Please help for the same, and i have used the solution provided by stackoverflow and other community

I have tried the solution to add     android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
in manifest file, but its not working.

items.component.ts method

```
private serverUrl = "http://portal.smallborrowing.com/get_user.php";

    extractData() {
        this.myService.getData(this.serverUrl).subscribe(data => this.profile=data);
        console.log(this.profile);
    }
```

item.service.ts method

```
getData(serverUrl) {
    return this.http.get(serverUrl);
}
```

Error

ERROR

`{
"headers": {
"normalizedNames": {},
"lazyUpdate": null,
"headers": {}
},
"status": 0,
"statusText": "Unknown Error",
"url": "http://portal.smallborrowing.com/get_user.php",
"ok": false,
"name": "HttpErrorResponse",
"message": "Http failure response for http://portal.smallborrowing.com/get_user.php: 0 Unknown Error",
"error": {
JS:     "originalStack": "Error: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to portal.smallborrowing.com not permitted\n    at new ZoneAwareError (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Smallborrowing/files/app/vendor.js:76023:33)\n    at onRequestComplete (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Smallborrowing/files/app/vendor.js:95301:34)\n    at Object.onComplete (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Smallborrowing/files/app/vendor.js:95290:13)",
JS:     "zoneAwareStack": "Error: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to portal.smallborrowing.com not permitted\n    at onRequestComplete (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Smallborrowing/files/app/vendor.js:953...`

get_user.php returns this data

`{"email":"John","password":"password"}`

Comment: Did you try a clean build after updating the manifest with `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`?

Comment: yes i did that 2 times

Comment: Was the issue reproduced in Playground when you hit the same url?

Comment: no iam not using playground , the setup is on my pc

Comment: I totally get it, but my intention was to verify whether it's a problem with your project setup, because just enabling this flag mostly fixes this issue.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am having the same issue with NS 8.0.9

Comment: Yes i have resolved the issue.Please add your domain in network_security_config.xml